# Error adding p-values manually to ggplot2 using stat_pvalue_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have plotted a 2-way interaction with 2 categorical variables using ggplot2, below is a simulated dataset:

```
set.seed(123)

id <- rep(1:50, each = 3)
condition <- rep(c("a", "b"), each = 1, times = 75)
trial <- rep(c("1", "2", "3"), each = 1, times = 50)
outcome <- rnorm(150, mean = 15, sd = 2.4)

df <- data.frame(id, condition, trial, outcome)

model <- aov(outcome ~ condition*trial, data = df)
summary(model)
```

I then conducted posthoc tests using emmeans:

```
emm_model <- emmeans(model, pairwise ~ trial | condition)
summary(emm_model)
```

And subsequently built a graph in ggplot2:

```
model_means <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(condition,trial) %>%
  get_summary_stats(outcome) 

gg_model <- ggplot(model_means, aes(x = condition, y = mean, fill = trial, color = trial)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF","#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF","#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 0.8)

gg_model
```

Now, I would like to add brackets with asterisks denoting the significance of the comparisons between trial 1, trial 2, and trial 3 within condition A and condition B, using the p-values obtained from emmeans.

I tried the following methods:

```
model_posthoc <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(condition) %>%
  t_test(outcome ~ trial, p.adjust.method = "holm")

model_posthoc <- model_posthoc %>%
  add_xy_position(x = "condition", dodge = 0.8)

gg_model + stat_pvalue_manual(model_posthoc, label = "p.adj", tip.length = 0.01)
```

and

```
gg_model + stat_pvalue_manual(compare_means(data = 
                       df %>% dplyr::group_by(condition), 
                       outcome ~ trial,
                     method = "t.test"), 
                    label = "p.adj", y.position = 15)
```

but both of them return the error

```
Adding missing grouping variables: `condition`Error:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `fill`
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)
```

Is there something I am missing with adding the significance values?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you specified a global mapping on the `fill` and `color` aesthetic in `ggplot()` which are inherited by all subsequent layers. As a consequence `stat_pvalue_manual` is also mapping `trial` on `fill` and `color` but as your dataset `model_posthoc` does not contain a column named `trial` you get an error. To fix that make `fill` and `color` local aesthetics of `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(model_means, aes(x = condition, y = mean)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = trial, color = trial),
    stat = "identity",
    position = "dodge", alpha = 0.5, size = 0.8
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#190C3EFF", "#9C2964FF", "#F8870EFF")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se, color = trial),
    width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 0.8
  ) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(model_posthoc, label = "p.adj", tip.length = 0.01)
```

[image]